# Unhandled exception in try/catch block

Tags: c#, exception

This one is really baking my noodle...

I've got some code. When I run it, Visual Studio complains about an unhandled exception. And, sure enough, there *is* an exception. However, it's blatently inside a try/catch block, so... *how is that "unhandled"??*

I've searched around, and the only relevant hit I can find is related to LINQ. But I'm not using any LINQ, so that can't be it.

The relevant code looks something like this:

```
try
{
  method.Invoke(target, new object[0]);
}
catch (MyException e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

The method being hit by `Invoke()` is different every time. Some of these methods really do throw exceptions - which is fine. But that's why I put it in a try-block! I don't understand why VS is complaining that the exception isn't handled.

(Yes, I have checked that the exception being thrown is a `MyException` object.)

At this point, my only guess is that it's somehow related to using reflection. I really need to fix this though... Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code only cathes instances of `MyException`, what execption are you being told is unhandled?

Comment: @TI As I say, the reported exception exactly matches the one I'm catching, including the full namespace path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the documentation for [`MethodInfo.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx).

> **Exceptions**
>
> TargetInvocationException - The invoked method or constructor throws an exception.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> If the invoked method throws an exception, the [`Exception.GetBaseException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.getbaseexception.aspx) method returns the exception.

Your exception is being wrapped in a [`TargetInvocationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx).

Comment: OMG. Ouch... That's just sneaky.

Comment: To be clear: I changed the exception type, and VS _still_ breaks on the exception. However, it now lets me continue after the exception...